Why are my new lights flickering?
I had three light fixtures connected to a Set of three way dimmable switches. They had halogen bulbs. I replaced one to see if I’d like it. The new light fixture has a LED bulb.
So one LED and two halogen worked fine. I purchased the other two new fixtures and installed them. But when I turned on either switch, the lights flicker and flash.
Any ideas what is going on?

The LED may not be dimmable and/or the dimmers may not be compatible with the new LEDs

Since you had a set of fixtures with halogen bulbs, it's very likely that the dimmer on those was not LED compatible. The LED bulb or fixture needs to be dimmable, and the dimmer also needs to be LED compatible.
Having the other two fixtures still being halogen could allow the dimmer to work (being sufficently loaded from those) while replacing them with LED fixtures exposed the problem. LED-compatible dimmers may have a variety of limitations you have to shop around: for example I have an old (now) set that require a minimum 32W LED load and thus can't be used on a single fixture (of any reasonable size.)
You can also get flashing with LED-compatible dimmers (usually at the dim end of adjustment) where there's some adjustment on the dimmer required (some have them, some don't) to bring the minimum adjustment into the range that works for the particular dimmable fixtures/bulbs connected.
